# view.View.onClickListener Error

Tags: android, eclipse

It keeps saying that the import view.View.OnClickListener is not being used, so i delete the import and reorganize the imports and then i keep an error in this part of the code that i posted. What is going on? When i delete the import the error is in private float getScaledVolume(int paramInt). The error says The local variable d2 may not have been initialized and then the rest of the code after the error says the code is unreachable.

```
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.AlertDialog;
    import android.app.AlertDialog.Builder;
    import android.app.Dialog;
    import android.content.DialogInterface;
    import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.media.AudioManager;
    import android.media.MediaPlayer;
    import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;
    import android.media.MediaRecorder;
    import android.os.Build;
    import android.os.Build.VERSION;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.KeyEvent;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.SeekBar;
    import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.sql.Timestamp;
    import java.util.Date;

    public class MediaCenter
  extends Activity
{
  private String FileName;
  private String Title;
  private Timestamp Ts;
  AudioManager audioManager;
  private SeekBar beatvol_bar;
  private Date date;
  private int lyric_offset = 550;
  private SeekBar lyricvol_bar;
  private MediaPlayer mPlayer = null;
  private MediaRecorder mRecorder = null;
  int maxVolume;
  private MediaCenter me = this;
  private SeekBar offset_bar;
  private String path;
  ImageView pauseButton;
  ImageView playButton;
  ImageView play_lyrics_recordingButton;
  ImageView play_recordingButton;
  private MediaPlayer rPlayer = null;
  ImageView recordButton;
  ImageView redownloadButton;
  ImageView saveButton;
  ImageView stopButton;
  ImageView stop_recordingButton;
  private long timestamp;
  private TextView tv;
  ImageView wwwButton;

  private float getScaledVolume(int paramInt)
  {
    double d1 = paramInt / 10;
    Log.d("MediaCenter", "vol in getScaledVolume is " + d1);
    double d2;
    if (d1 <= this.maxVolume / 20) {
      d2 = d1 / 23.0D;
    }
    for (;;)
    {
      return (float)d2;
      if (d1 <= this.maxVolume / 19) {
        d2 = d1 / 22.0D;
      } else if (d1 <= this.maxVolume / 18) {
        d2 = d1 / 21.0D;
      } else if (d1 <= this.maxVolume / 17) {
        d2 = d1 / 20.0D;
      } else if (d1 <= this.maxVolume / 16) {
        d2 = d1 / 19.0D;
      } else if (d1 <= this.maxVolume / 15) {
        d2 = d1 / 18.0D;
      } else if (d1 <= this.maxVolume / 14) {
        d2 = d1 / 17.0D;
      } else if (d1 <= this.maxVolume / 13) {
        d2 = d1 / 16.0D;
      } else if (d1 <= this.maxVolume / 12) {
        d2 = d1 / 15.0D;
      } else if (d1 <= this.maxVolume / 11) {
        d2 = d1 / 14.0D;
      } else if (d1 <= this.maxVolume / 10) {
        d2 = d1 / 13.0D;
      } else if (d1 <= this.maxVolume / 9) {
        d2 = d1 / 12.0D;
      } else if (d1 <= this.maxVolume / 8) {
        d2 = d1 / 11.0D;
      } else if (d1 <= this.maxVolume / 7) {
        d2 = d1 / 10.0D;
      } else if (d1 <= this.maxVolume / 6) {
        d2 = d1 / 9.0D;
      } else if (d1 <= this.maxVolume / 5) {
        d2 = d1 / 8.0D;
      } else if (d1 <= this.maxVolume / 4) {
        d2 = d1 / 7.0D;
      } else if (d1 <= this.maxVolume / 3) {
        d2 = d1 / 6.0D;
      } else {
        d2 = paramInt / 10;
      }
    }
  }

  private boolean insertRap()
  {
    this.date = new Date();
    this.Ts = new Timestamp(this.date.getTime());
    this.timestamp = this.Ts.getTime();
  }

  private void pausePlayer()
  {
    if (this.mPlayer != null)
    {
      this.mPlayer.pause();
      if (isFinishing())
      {
        this.mPlayer.stop();
        this.mPlayer.release();
      }
    }
    if (this.rPlayer != null)
    {
      this.rPlayer.pause();
      if (isFinishing())
      {
        this.rPlayer.stop();
        this.rPlayer.release();
      }
    }
  }

  private void playBeats(String paramString, int paramInt)
  {
    Log.d("MediaCenter", "playing: " + paramString);
    float f = getScaledVolume(this.beatvol_bar.getProgress());
    try
    {
      if ((paramString.equals("one")) || (paramString.equals("two")) || (paramString.equals("three")))
      {
        if (paramString.equals("one")) {
          this.mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.one);
        }
        if (paramString.equals("two")) {
          this.mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.two);
        }
        if (paramString.equals("pass_the_dutch")) {
          this.mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.three);
        }
        this.mPlayer.setLooping(false);
        this.mPlayer.setVolume(f, f);
        this.mPlayer.start();
        this.mPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener()
        {
          public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer paramAnonymousMediaPlayer)
          {
            MediaCenter.this.recordButton.setImageResource(R.id.record);
            MediaCenter.this.stopRecording();
          }
        });
        return;
      }
      this.mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
      this.mPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener()
      {
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer paramAnonymousMediaPlayer)
        {
          MediaCenter.this.recordButton.setImageResource(R.id.record);
          MediaCenter.this.stopRecording();
        }
      });
      FileInputStream localFileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(this.path + paramString));
      this.mPlayer.setDataSource(localFileInputStream.getFD());
      this.mPlayer.prepare();
      this.mPlayer.setLooping(false);
      this.mPlayer.setVolume(f, f);
      this.mPlayer.start();
      return;
    }
    catch (Exception localException)
    {
      Log.e("MediaCenter", "Play MP3 Failed" + localException.getMessage());
      localException.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  private void playLyrics(String paramString, int paramInt)
  {
    float f = getScaledVolume(this.lyricvol_bar.getProgress());
    try
    {
      this.rPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
      this.rPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener()
      {
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer paramAnonymousMediaPlayer)
        {
          MediaCenter.this.recordButton.setImageResource(R.id.record);
          MediaCenter.this.stopRecording();
        }
      });
      FileInputStream localFileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(this.path + paramString));
      this.rPlayer.setDataSource(localFileInputStream.getFD());
      this.rPlayer.prepare();
      this.rPlayer.setLooping(false);
      this.rPlayer.setVolume(f, f);
      this.rPlayer.start();
      return;
    }
    catch (Exception localException)
    {
      Log.e("MediaCenter", "Play MP3 Failed" + localException.getMessage());
      localException.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  private void playLyricsAndBeats()
  {
    playLyrics("r_" + this.FileName, this.maxVolume);
    try
    {
      Thread.sleep(this.lyric_offset);
      playBeats(this.FileName, this.maxVolume);
      return;
    }
    catch (InterruptedException localInterruptedException)
    {
      for (;;)
      {
        localInterruptedException.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }

  private void setUpUI()
  {
    setContentView(R.layout.media);
    setUpSeekBars();
    setUpTitle();
    setUpButtons();
  }

  private void startPlaying()
  {
    if (this.mPlayer == null)
    {
      playBeats(this.FileName, this.maxVolume);
      return;
    }
    this.mPlayer.start();
  }

  private void startRecording()
  {
    try
    {
      int i = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
      this.mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
      this.mRecorder.setAudioSource(1);
      if ((i < 16) && (i < 10)) {}
      this.mRecorder.setOutputFormat(1);
      this.mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(1);
      MediaRecorder.getAudioSourceMax();
      File localFile = new File(this.path + "r_" + this.FileName);
      if (localFile.exists()) {
        localFile.delete();
      }
      this.mRecorder.setOutputFile(this.path + "r_" + this.FileName);
      this.mRecorder.prepare();
      this.mRecorder.start();
      return;
    }
    catch (Exception localException)
    {
      Log.e("MediaCenter", "MediaRecorder Failed: " + localException.getMessage());
      localException.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  private void stopPlaying()
  {
    if (this.mPlayer != null)
    {
      this.mPlayer.release();
      this.mPlayer = null;
    }
    if (this.rPlayer != null)
    {
      this.rPlayer.release();
      this.rPlayer = null;
    }
  }

  private void stopRecording()
  {
    if (this.mRecorder != null)
    {
      this.mRecorder.release();
      this.mRecorder = null;
    }
  }

  public void onCreate(Bundle paramBundle)
  {
    super.onCreate(paramBundle);
    this.audioManager = ((AudioManager)getSystemService("audio"));
    this.maxVolume = this.audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(3);
    this.audioManager = ((AudioManager)getSystemService("audio"));
    this.audioManager.setMode(0);
    this.maxVolume = this.audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(3);
    Log.d("MediaCenter", "Got Max Volume: " + this.maxVolume);
    Bundle localBundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (localBundle != null)
    {
      this.Title = localBundle.getString("Title");
      this.path = localBundle.getString("path");
      this.FileName = localBundle.getString("FileName");
      setUpUI();
      return;
    }
    Log.d("MediaCenter", "Could not get Extras");
  }

  protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int paramInt)
  {
    switch (paramInt)
    {
    default: 
      new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setCancelable(false).setTitle("Redownload?").setMessage("If the song did not completely download, this will attempt to download the song again.").setPositiveButton("Redownload", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
      {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface paramAnonymousDialogInterface, int paramAnonymousInt)
        {
          MediaCenter.this.stopRecording();
          MediaCenter.this.stopPlaying();
          File localFile = new File(MediaCenter.this.path + MediaCenter.this.FileName);
          if (localFile.exists()) {
            localFile.delete();
          }
          Intent localIntent = new Intent(MediaCenter.this.me, MediaCenter.class);
          localIntent.putExtra("Title", MediaCenter.this.Title);
          localIntent.putExtra("FileName", MediaCenter.this.FileName);
          MediaCenter.this.startActivity(localIntent);
          MediaCenter.this.me.finish();
        }
      }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
      {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface paramAnonymousDialogInterface, int paramAnonymousInt) {}
      }).create();
    }
  }
  public void onDestroy()
  {
    super.onDestroy();
    stopPlaying();
    stopRecording();
  }

  public boolean onKeyDown(int paramInt, KeyEvent paramKeyEvent)
  {
    if (paramInt != 24) {}
    return super.onKeyDown(paramInt, paramKeyEvent);
  }

  public boolean onKeyUp(int paramInt, KeyEvent paramKeyEvent)
  {
    if (paramInt != 24) {}
    return super.onKeyUp(paramInt, paramKeyEvent);
  }

  protected void onPause()
  {
    super.onPause();
    stopPlaying();
    stopRecording();
  }

  protected void onResume()
  {
    super.onResume();

    if (this.mPlayer != null) {
      this.mPlayer.start();
    }
    if (this.rPlayer != null) {
      this.rPlayer.start();
    }
  }

  public void onStop()
  {
    super.onStop();
    stopPlaying();
    stopRecording();
  }

  protected void setUpButtons()
  {
    this.playButton = ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.play));
    this.pauseButton = ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.pause));
    this.stopButton = ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.stop));
    this.recordButton = ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.record));
    this.play_recordingButton = ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.play_recording));
    this.play_lyrics_recordingButton = ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.play_lyrics_recording));
    this.stop_recordingButton = ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.stop_recording));
    this.saveButton = ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.save));
    this.redownloadButton = ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.redownload));
    this.playButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
      public void onClick(View paramAnonymousView)
      {
        Toast.makeText(MediaCenter.this, "Play", 0).show();
        MediaCenter.this.recordButton.setImageResource(R.id.record);
        MediaCenter.this.stopRecording();
        MediaCenter.this.startPlaying();
      }
    });
    this.pauseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
      public void onClick(View paramAnonymousView)
      {
        Toast.makeText(MediaCenter.this, "Pause", 0).show();
        MediaCenter.this.recordButton.setImageResource(R.id.record);
        MediaCenter.this.stopRecording();
        MediaCenter.this.pausePlayer();
      }
    });
    this.stopButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
      public void onClick(View paramAnonymousView)
      {
        Toast.makeText(MediaCenter.this, "Stop", 0).show();
        MediaCenter.this.recordButton.setImageResource(R.id.record);
        MediaCenter.this.stopRecording();
        MediaCenter.this.stopPlaying();
      }
    });
    this.recordButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
      public void onClick(View paramAnonymousView)
      {
        Toast.makeText(MediaCenter.this, "Recording", 0).show();
        MediaCenter.this.recordButton.setImageResource(R.id.record);
        MediaCenter.this.stopRecording();
        MediaCenter.this.stopPlaying();
        MediaCenter.this.startRecording();
        MediaCenter.this.startPlaying();
      }
    });
    this.play_recordingButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
      public void onClick(View paramAnonymousView)
      {
        Toast.makeText(MediaCenter.this, "Play Recording", 0).show();
        MediaCenter.this.recordButton.setImageResource(R.id.record);
        MediaCenter.this.stopRecording();
        MediaCenter.this.stopPlaying();
        MediaCenter.this.playLyricsAndBeats();
      }
    });
    this.play_lyrics_recordingButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
      public void onClick(View paramAnonymousView)
      {
        Toast.makeText(MediaCenter.this, "Play Lyrics", 0).show();
        MediaCenter.this.recordButton.setImageResource(R.id.record);
        MediaCenter.this.stopRecording();
        MediaCenter.this.stopPlaying();
        MediaCenter.this.playLyrics("r_" + MediaCenter.this.FileName, MediaCenter.this.maxVolume);
      }
    });
    this.stop_recordingButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
      public void onClick(View paramAnonymousView)
      {
        Toast.makeText(MediaCenter.this, "Stop Recording", 0).show();
        MediaCenter.this.recordButton.setImageResource(R.id.record);
        MediaCenter.this.stopRecording();
        MediaCenter.this.stopPlaying();
      }
    });
    this.saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
      public void onClick(View paramAnonymousView)
      {
        MediaCenter.this.recordButton.setImageResource(R.id.record);
        MediaCenter.this.stopRecording();
        MediaCenter.this.stopPlaying();
        if (Utils.testRecordingFileExists(MediaCenter.this.path + "r_" + MediaCenter.this.FileName))
        {
          if ((MediaCenter.this.insertRap()) && (Utils.CopyFile(MediaCenter.this.path + "r_" + MediaCenter.this.FileName, MediaCenter.this.path + "r_" + MediaCenter.this.timestamp + MediaCenter.this.FileName))) {
            Toast.makeText(MediaCenter.this, "Rap Saved", 0).show();
          }
          return;
        }
        Toast.makeText(MediaCenter.this, "Please Create Lyrics", 0).show();
      }
    });
    this.wwwButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
      public void onClick(View paramAnonymousView)
      {
        if (Utils.testRecordingFileExists(MediaCenter.this.path + "r_" + MediaCenter.this.FileName))
        {
          if (Utils.testFileSize(MediaCenter.this.path + "r_" + MediaCenter.this.FileName))
          {
            MediaCenter.this.showDialog(0);
            return;
          }
          Toast.makeText(MediaCenter.this, "Lyrics Too Short", 0).show();
          return;
        }
        Toast.makeText(MediaCenter.this, "Please Create Lyrics", 0).show();
      }
    });
    this.redownloadButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
      public void onClick(View paramAnonymousView)
      {
        MediaCenter.this.showDialog(1);
      }
    });
  }

  protected void setUpSeekBars()
  {
    this.offset_bar = ((SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.offset_bar));
    this.offset_bar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new offsetBarListener(null));
    this.lyricvol_bar = ((SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.lyricvol_bar));
    this.lyricvol_bar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new lyricvolBarListener(null));
    this.lyricvol_bar.setMax(10 * this.maxVolume);
    this.lyricvol_bar.setProgress(5 * this.maxVolume);
    this.beatvol_bar = ((SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.beatvol_bar));
    this.beatvol_bar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new beatvolBarListener(null));
    this.beatvol_bar.setMax(10 * this.maxVolume);
    this.beatvol_bar.setProgress(5 * this.maxVolume);
  }

  protected void setUpTitle()
  {
    this.tv = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.song_title));
    this.tv.setText(this.Title);
  }

  private class beatvolBarListener
    implements SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener
  {
    private beatvolBarListener(SeekBar paramBeatVolBar) {}

    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar paramSeekBar, int paramInt, boolean paramBoolean)
    {
      float f = MediaCenter.this.getScaledVolume(paramInt);
      Log.d("MediaCenter", "Set Volume from: " + paramInt / 10 + " and scale it to: " + f);
      if (MediaCenter.this.mPlayer != null) {
        MediaCenter.this.mPlayer.setVolume(f, f);
      }
    }

    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar paramSeekBar) {}

    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar paramSeekBar) {}
  }

  private class lyricvolBarListener
    implements SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener
  {
    private lyricvolBarListener(SeekBar paramLyricVolBar) {}

    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar paramSeekBar, int paramInt, boolean paramBoolean)
    {
      float f = MediaCenter.this.getScaledVolume(paramInt);
      Log.d("MediaCenter", "Set Volume from: " + paramInt / 10 + " and scale it to: " + f);
      if (MediaCenter.this.rPlayer != null) {
        MediaCenter.this.rPlayer.setVolume(f, f);
      }
    }

    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar paramSeekBar) {}

    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar paramSeekBar) {}
  }

  private class offsetBarListener
    implements SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener
  {
    private offsetBarListener(SeekBar paramOffSetBar) {}

    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar paramSeekBar, int paramInt, boolean paramBoolean)
    {
      MediaCenter.this.lyric_offset = paramInt;
    }

    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar paramSeekBar)
    {
      MediaCenter.this.stopPlaying();
      MediaCenter.this.stopRecording();
    }

    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar paramSeekBar) {}
  }
}
```

Comment: But you do not use it

Comment: `an error in this part of the code` Which error do you get? Where? Which line?

Comment: edited my question to be more specific with the full code and where the error is

Comment: Ok, but what is the error message?

Comment: The local variable d2 may not have been initialized

Answer (score 0):

About your **first problem**: `The local variable d2 may not have been initialized`

You should give your d2 variable an initial value like for example:
`double d2 = 0;` instead of: `double d2;`. You were only assigning a value inside of an if-statement.

---

About the **2nd problem**: `unreachable code`

Take a look at your code snippet here:

```
for (;;)
{
  return (float)d2;
  if (d1 <= this.maxVolume / 19) {
    d2 = d1 / 22.0D;
  //...
```

the code after the return statement is not reachable, because it *always* returns before all your if statements get executed. Rethink this code and think about what you want to achieve here.

Comment: ok i tried that and what happens is that from if (d1 <= this.maxVolume / 19) all the way to d2 = paramInt / 10; says the code is unreachable and to remove it

Comment: Yes, everything after return won't get executed. I just copied this snipped from your question. You will have to completely rethink this code. A for-loop that starts with a return statement does not make any sense. You probably want to return _after_ all your if-statements.

Comment: I don't know how you want to calculate this d2 variable, but returning it before you finish calculations is wrong. Also I don't see the need of the for-loop here. Anyhow, as a start move the `return (float)d2;` after the last else statement to get rid of the unreachable code warning.